# Missing fireball.docking dll reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I had downloaded a C# project from the net.When I opened it in VS2010 and tried to run it it showed Error

> "The type or namespace name 'Fireball' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

When I checked the *References* Folder it showed a **!** symbol on **Fireball.Docking** and **fireball.Windows.Form**

Can Somebody pls help me on how to get those dll files?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.This is not the type of question we want here on SO. To know how to formulate a good question please refere to the [F.A.Q](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) section. As for your question,the class is missing.  Where to get it? Probably where you got the project in the first place.

Comment: I googled for "c# fireball" and came up with [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetfireball/).

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as answered if you found out what you needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have this current `DLL` included in your project. You could go back to where you downloaded the project and try to find the missing `DLL`. If you are sure that you have it with the project, go to the reference section where you have the `!` and delete it. Then :

- Right click `References`
- Click `Add Reference...`
- Browse to your  `Dll` and add it.